# 'I thought I would ..., once it is/was'

Tags: conditionals

Which verb should be used in place of "is" which is currently used in condition in the following sentence:

"They thought that subsequent contributions to the joint venture would be made into the designated holding company through purchase of its additional shares, once the shareholders agreement (is?) signed."

Comment: If *at time of utterance* the agreement still hasn't yet been signed, it would be at least possible (but not necessarily *required*, in all registers) to use ***is***. Mostly people would just use ***was*** anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's begin by changing the whole sentence into present tense.

"They think subsequent contributions to the joint venture will be made into the designated holding company through purchase of its additional shares, once the shareholders agreement **is** signed".

Your sentence is totally in the past tense and quite similar to the *reported speech* format. Therefore, the correct verb would be "was".

In order to better understand this, let's consider the following:

Direct speech: "I think I am sick", he said.
Reported speech: He said (that) he thought he **was** sick.

That said, when it comes to something that's still valid or true, present tense would be appropriate as shown here:

DS: "My name is Ron."
RS: He said that his name **is** Ron.

In your context, **was** would be correct.*

Answer (score -1):

"I thought I'd do it once it 'is' done" is a little imbalanced in terms of tense. The sentence begins with the past tense (*thought*), then proceeds to a modal (*would*) which suggests future tense, and then lands up in present because of *is*. I think a better alternative would be "I thought I'd do it once it has been done" or "I think I will do it once it is done". These suggestions were based on what my teacher taught me: a sentence should mostly maintain the same tense till the end. I hope that helps!

Comment: @ Aishwarya A R: As for your closing remark, "... a sentence should mostly maintain the same tense till the end", I believe what you say here needs further illustration by means of examples. There could be sentences with two or more clauses, which may follow a certain rule in grammar and not necessarily have all verbs in the same tense.

Comment: @Sankarane I remember my teacher mentioning that in class. Purists and some grammarians would agree on this matter. I found this on the internet: http://i.imgur.com/HjPSkIt.jpg. Check it out and let me know if you still disagree.

Comment: What's required to support your answer is an authentic source from the works of "purists and grammarians" and with grammatical explanation of the statement,  "... a sentence should mostly maintain the same tense till the end". Fiction may not serve as one, I'm afraid.

Comment: This article is perfect: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/maintaining-the-same-verb-tense-in-your-sentences.html

Comment: @ Aishwarya A R : 
A sentence such as, "I think you will agree" uses two different tenses, viz., present and future. As your answer explains, "would" doesn't suggest future tense. "would be" is conditional present tense, not of the same tense as "They thought...", which is past indefinite. Your answer doesn't address the OP's question nor is it helpful by suggesting a definitive answer. Your statement, "...maintain the same tense till the end" sounds quite fuzzy to me.

Comment: If you read that article, you'd have understood that sometimes shift in tenses is unavoidable. Your example supports the content of that article: "I **think** you will **agree**". Both the 'verb' tenses are in the present tense.

Comment: "will agree" is future indefinite tense! I give up. You probably should revise conjugations before attempting to help others on grammar.